# Условие с in_array не работает

Tags: php, массивы

Почему это условие не истинно?

```
if (in_array(array('3','4','5'), $virtuemart_shoppergroup_ids, false))
```

И это:

```
if (in_array(array(3,4,5), $virtuemart_shoppergroup_ids, false))
```

Ну и это:

```
if (in_array(array(3,4,5), $virtuemart_shoppergroup_ids))
```

Если `$virtuemart_shoppergroup_ids` содержит в себе:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
)
```

Comment: Неправильные параметры для функции in_array, посмотрите мануал

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php

Comment: Я смотрел мануал... Я так понимаю массив значений эта функция не может найти в массиве? А только строку или число в массиве?

Comment: да. если хотите найти равные значения в нескольких массивах - используйте array_intersect

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь да, массивы в массивах она искать не может

Comment: Как можно найти ``('3','4','5')`` в ``$virtuemart_shoppergroup_ids``, если там такого нет?\

Comment: @Peresada Может. В мануале даже пример есть.

Comment: В том то и дело что может и пример есть, мануал старый смотрел. Хотя в старом мануале тоже этот пример есть...

Comment: @Эникейщик В мануале он ищет массив в многомерном массиве. То есть там искомый массив является элементом массива в $haystack,  это не одно и то же. Я имел ввиду однородные массивы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что 1ый аргумент - это то, что ищем, а 2ой - в каком массиве ищем. Читайте мануал

P.S. третий параметр `false` бесполезен, так как он по умолчанию установлен в `false`

**Update:**

in_array вернет true, только если первый аргумент является элементом 2ого аргумента

```
$simpleHaystack = [ 1, 2, 3 ]; // одномерный массив
$multiHaystack = [ [ 1 , 2 ] , 3]; // многомерный массив
$needle = [ 1, 2 ];

var_dump( in_array( $needle, $simpleHaystack ) ); // false, потому что в массиве [1,2,3] нет элемента [1,2]
var_dump( in_array( $needle, $multiHaystack ) ); // true, потому что в массиве [[1,2],3] есть элемент [1,2]
```

Comment: Противоречит мануалу, потому что, вторым параметром должен быть составной массив в котором и исходный массив и искомый.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь внимательней с мануалом ознакомьтесь. $needle - это искомый элемент массива $haystack. $needle может являться чем угодно, и in_array выдаст true только если он является элементом $haystack. `in_array(array(1,2) array(array(1,2)))` - сработает, но `in_array(array(1,2),array(1,2))` - нет

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь 1-й параметр что ищем, 2-й где ищем. 3-й 'strict type' флаг. У вас массив строк в котором вы пытаетесь найти другой массив! При этом перепутав порядок параметров для функции...

Comment: Ну и что вам не нравится что я ищу не 1 значение а 3? У меня связь многие ко многим.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь функция in_array не может принимать в первом аргументе несколько элементов. Она принимает только 1 элемент, который в свою очередь может являться массивом.

Answer (score -2):

Вот это работает.

```
        $haystack = array(array(3,4,5), $virtuemart_shoppergroup_ids);

        if (in_array(array(3,4,5), $haystack)) {

        }
```

Comment: все верно, об этом Вам и написали в комментариях и ответах. Однако это не является ответом на поставленный вопрос. В вопросе Вы изначально некорректно использовали функцию in_array

Comment: @Peresada То есть этот код верный, я правильно понял? Если так то вопросов нет. У нас же хорошее сообщество, мирное и дружелюбное.

Comment: Верный, конечно. В данном случае `$haystack` является многомерным массивом, в котором `in_array` находит элемент `array(3,4,5)` при этом `$virtuemart_shoppergroup_ids` является бесполезной переменной в данном случае

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь посмотрите на это условие: `if ( count(array_intersect($array1, $array2)) > 0 )`, это не то что вам нужно?

Comment: @Den Нет это тоже не будет работать так как она сравнивает массивы целиком а мне надо сравнить несколько чисел с возможным наличием одного или нескольких чисел в массиве. По сути проще провести цикл на проверку 3, 4, 5

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь вызов `array_intersect` возвращяет массив из значений которые присудствуют в обоих начальных массивах `($array1, $array2)`. Если его длина т.е. вызов функции `count` больше нуля то массивы пересекаются. Если вам нужен сам результат пересечения то можно написать как `if ( count($resultArray = array_intersect($array1, $array2)) > 0 )` и использовать `$resultArray` внутри блока `if`.